# Creating a decision tree in R

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am an intern and my boss wants me to make a decision tree that results in the likelihood of someone being / becoming diabetic. I am extremely new to R and currently the only one that I work with that is using R... I need the decision tree to be based on the following criteria:

```
if(A1CValue >= 8)
{print('highly likely')}
else if(BSValue >= 140)
{print("highly likely")}
else if(DBPValue >= 80)
{print("highly likely")}
else if(SBPValue >= 140)
{print("highly likely")}
else 
{print("less likely")
}
```

Can anyone assist me in the coding to put this into a decision tree?
Thanks in advance,
Laura

Comment: How do you know that these creterias are correct? Someone already made a decision tree and received thiese results? Also, what do you mean by "your boss wants you to make a decision tree" if you already have the rules? You mean that you want the plot? You can take a look in partykit package too http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/partykit.pdf

Comment: Maybe the function rpart() in base R, and the packages plot.rpart/rpart.plot also warrant a mention here?

Comment: Learn a bit of R first. Learn about data frames and functions. Then you can write a function that operates on a data frame and returns the result of the decision tree. The decision tree function would look a lot like your sample code, except setting the result rather than printing something out.

Comment: Well, the criteria has been determined from medical journals of the limits for each test result.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have splitting criteria then there is no point in using R to create a tree... just draw the tree in whatever graphic software you like!

The best thing, however, would be to let R do the job.

You may want to look at packages such as `tree` or `randomForest`.

I may also suggest these videos from the [StatLearning course](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/HumanitiesScience/StatLearning/Winter2014/about) (be sure to check out their free book [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) too!)

[8.1 Tree-based methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ENTbK3yQUQ)
[8.2 More details on Trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfPR7Xhdokc)
[8.3 Classification trees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPEJoITBbQ4)
[8.4 Bagging and Random forests](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lq_xzBRIWm4)
[8.5 Boosting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3MdBNysk9w)
[8.R Tree-Based Methods in R part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wZUXtvAtDc) and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY7oWGXb77o)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look into the links you have provided.